# error in casting from int to bool

Tags: c++, int, boolean

The following program:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
void f(int x){
    if(x)cout<<x;
}
int main(){
    int x=3;
    f(x);

    return 0;
}
```

gives output as:

```
3
```

Shouldn't there be no output as any number in c++ except 0 is considered as true?
However if I change the above program to:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
void f(int x){
    //changed here
    if(x==0)cout<<x;
}
int main(){
    int x=3;
    f(x);

    return 0;
}
```

the program behaves correctly i.e. no output. Can anybody help me???

Comment: You've got it mixed up. Any number except zero is *truthy*, not falsy.

Comment: You answered your own question.

Comment: Everything but 0 is true, yes. That means 3 is true...

Comment: Please think again carefully. Maybe have a bit of sleep first. x = 3 falls into the category "every number except 0".

Comment: Everyone has a lapse sometime. Nothing to do with being new to C++ though...

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't there be no output as any number in c++ except 0 is considered as true?

As you say, any number except 0 is considered true. 3 is not 0, so 3 is true.

There is an implied `!= 0` when you use an `int` in an `if` statement. These two statements are equivalent:

```
if (x)      cout << x;
if (x != 0) cout << x;
```

Both of them will execute when `x == 3`.